# Using Sed through subprocess.call in python to conduct in file replacements

Tags: python, bash, sed, subprocess

I've got a column in one file that I'd like to replace with a column in another file. I'm trying to use sed to do this within python, but I'm not sure I'm doing it correctly. Maybe the code will make things more clear:

```
 20 for line in infile1.readlines()[1:]:
 21         element = re.split("\t", line)
 22         IID.append(element[1])
 23         FID.append(element[0])
 24 
 25 os.chdir(binary_dir)
 26 
 27 for files in os.walk(binary_dir):
 28         for file in files:
 29                 for name in file:
 30                         if name.endswith(".fam"):
 31                                 infile2 = open(name, 'r+')
 32 
 33 for line in infile2.readlines():
 34         parts = re.split(" ", line)
 35         Part1.append(parts[0])
 36         Part2.append(parts[1])
 37 
 38 for i in range(len(Part2)):
 39         if Part2[i] in IID:
 40                 regex = '"s/\.*' + Part2[i] + '/' + Part1[i] + ' ' + Part2[i] + '/"' + ' ' + phenotype 
 41                 print regex
 42                 subprocess.call(["sed", "-i.orig", regex], shell=True)
```

This is what print regex does. The system appears to hang during the sed process, as it remains there for quite some time without doing anything.

```
"s/\.*131006/201335658-01 131006/" /Users/user1/Desktop/phenotypes2
```

Thanks for your help, and let me know if you need further clarification!

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `sed` if you have all the power of Python?

Comment: To be honest, I couldn’t see how to do this in Python. The reason I'm using Sed is that the phenotypes file I’m working on has 9 columns and I want to replace the first one only without overwriting the entire file.

Comment: Try with `Python Regular Expressions` - https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html. For instance the `re.sub()` method... Do you need an example?

Comment: @AndreiBoyanov An example would be much appreciated. Thank you for pointing out re.sub()!

Comment: unrelated: use `for line in infile2:` instead of `for line in infile2.readlines():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `sed` if you have Python and the `re` module. Here is an example of how to use `re` to replace a given pattern in a string.

```
>>> import re
>>> line = "abc def ghi"
>>> new_line = re.sub("abc", "123", line)
>>> new_line
'123 def ghi'
>>>
```

Of course this is only one way to do that in Python. I feel that for you `str.replace()` will do the job too.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is `shell=True` that is used together with a list argument. Either drop `shell=True` or use a string argument (the complete shell command) instead:

```
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(["sed", "-i.orig", regex])
```

otherwise the arguments (`'-i.orig'` and `regex`) are passed to `/bin/sh` instead of `sed`.

The second issue is that you haven't provided input files and therefore `sed` expects data from stdin that it is why it appears to hang.

If you want to make changes in files inplace, you could use [`fileinput` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput

files = ['/Users/user1/Desktop/phenotypes2'] # if it is None it behaves like sed
for line in fileinput.input(files, backup='.orig', inplace=True):
    print re.sub(r'\.*131006', '201335658-01 13100', line),
```

`fileinput.input()` redirects stdout to the current file i.e., `print` changes the file.

The comma sets `sys.stdout.softspace` to avoid duplicate newlines.